# Evernote from vim

Tags: vim, evernote

I search a way to edit evernote notes from vim

I begin with this

```
#!/bin/bash
evernoteDir="$HOME/Library/Application*Support/Evernote/data"
dataDir=$(ls -trlh $evernoteDir| tail -n 1| awk '{print $NF}')
contentDir="$evernoteDir/$dataDir/content"
file=$(ls -trlh $contentDir | tail -n 1| awk '{print $NF}')
vim -c 's/div>/div>\r/g' $contentDir/$file/content.html
```

https://gist.github.com/1256416

or maybe create a vim plugin for this ...

you have any suggestion?

**EDIT**:

for a more simple edition of the evernote note in html format, I make this vim function

```
" Markup function {{{ 
    fun! MkdToHtml() "{{{
        " markdown to html
        silent! execute '%s/  $/<br\/>/g'
        silent! execute '%s/\*\*\(.*\)\*\*/<b>\1<\/b>/g'
        silent! execute '%s/\t*###\(.*\)/<H3>\1<\/H3>/g'
    endf "}}}
    command! -complete=command MkdToHtml call MkdToHtml()
    nn <silent> <leader>mm :MkdToHtml<CR>
" }}}
```

and a vim function for open the last note edited

```
fun! LastEvernote() "{{{
    " a better solution is with evernote api
    let evernoteDir=expand("$HOME")."/Library/Application*Support/Evernote/data"
    let dataDir=system("ls -trlh ".evernoteDir."| tail -n 1| awk '{print $NF}'")
    let contentDir=evernoteDir."/".dataDir."/content"
    let contentDir=substitute(contentDir,"\n","",'g')
    let note=system("ls -trlh ".contentDir." | tail -n 1| awk '{print $NF}'")
    let note=substitute(note,"\n","",'g')
    sil! exec 'sp '.contentDir.'/'.note.'/content.html'
    sil! exec '1s/>/>\r/g'
    sil! exec '%s/<br.*\/>/<br\/>\r/g'
    sil! exec '%s/<\//\r<\//g'
    sil! exec 'g/^\s*$/d'
    normal gg
    sil! exec '1,4fo'
    sil! exec '$-1,$fo'
endf
```

https://gist.github.com/1289727

Comment: why to superuser? if is a development question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Geeknote (http://www.geeknote.me/)

"Edit your Evernote notes with any console editor you like - nano, vi, vim, mcedit, etc ...
Save changes and Geeknote will automatically upload them to Evernote."